# Portrait Mode of video in android java

Tags: video, orientation, android-videoview, portrait

How can i set portrait mode in video with android java from android 9 to higher

i tried to set it by videoview, playerview, exoplayer with this function : setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
but this change only the width and the height for portrait mode but the content always is staying with landscape mode